# Android animation pivot issue

Tags: android, android-animation, objectanimator

So, my first animation is this:

```
ObjectAnimator translation1 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mImage1, "TranslationY", mImage1.getTranslationY(), 0);
    translation1.setDuration(ANIM);
    translation1.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
            mImage1.setPivotY(0);

            ObjectAnimator scaleX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mImage1, "scaleX", 1, 0.5f);
            ObjectAnimator scaleY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mImage1, "scaleY", 1, 0.5f);
            ObjectAnimator alphaAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mImage1, "alpha", mImage1.getAlpha(), 0.1f);
            AnimatorSet set1 = new AnimatorSet();
            set1.playTogether(scaleX, scaleY, alphaAnim);
            set1.setDuration(ANIM);
            set1.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {

        }
    });
    translation1.start();
```

I set pivotY to 0, everything works really good.

Now, the second part, since I scaled that view, when I try to set pivot Y or pivot X, it is moving view left/right/up/down. I have tried with:

```
mImage1.setPivotX((mImage1.getWidth() * mImage1.getScaleX()) / 100);
    mImage1.setPivotY(mImage1.getHeight() * (-mImage1.getScaleY() * 100) / 100);
    mImage1.setPivotX(-mImage1.getWidth() * mImage1.getScaleX() / 100);
```

but none of these things work. Can someone explain me how to set pivot to the View Height and 0 for width?

Comment: @DeepakKumar this is not what im looking for. I need to use ObjectAnimator so it sets property to the views.